# Errro login in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to make a login in asp.net but the values I am entering are not being taken.

I have the following lines of code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Usuarios log)
{
    var usuario= db.Usuarios.Where(x => x.UsuNombre.Equals(log.UsuPass) && x.UsuPass.Equals(log.UsuPass)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (usuario != null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Notification = "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos";
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in this line. You are comparing user name with user password.

var usuario= db.Usuarios.Where(x => **x.UsuNombre.Equals(log.UsuPass)** && x.UsuPass.Equals(log.UsuPass)).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Thanks I corrected that but it still doesn't work.
It is as if it did not take the data I entered.

Comment: @pallavdubey Thanks I corrected that but it still doesn't work. It is as if it did not take the data I entered. –

Comment: Compare with `==` in your statement: `var usuario= db.Usuarios.Where(x => x.UsuNombre == log.UsuNombre && x.UsuPass == log.UsuPass).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: try using watch to your `log` variable and see if your getting correct data from your api request.

Answer (score 1):

Provide userName or Email of user

var usuario= db.Usuarios.Where(x => x.UsuNombre.Equals(log.UserEmail) && x.UsuPass.Equals(log.UsuPass)).FirstOrDefault();

you are only comparing userPassword for both the credential